# What is the right choice of XML encoding for Latin extended

Tags: php, database, encoding, collation

Ok, I need to creat DB interaction for Latin extended caracters such as: ŠšĐđČčĆćŽž etc..

Now one way is to set encoding to UTF (which result DB data caracters to get converted to Å¡Å¡Å¡ (using latin1_swedish_ci colation)..

This works fine while fetching data, unless I need to limit the length of th field, than the problem is when split occures in the middle of Å¡, the result caracter is ?? instead of Ć..

So a simple question, which encoding to use in HTML, and which colation to use inside DB to retain the original caracters.

THANK YOU

`

```
<!doctype html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>

<?php

$dbx = new mysqli('localhost','root','pass','dbtester') or die ('error with   connection');

$query = $dbx->prepare ("SELECT id, cont FROM dbtester");                                   
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($id, $cont);

while($query->fetch()):

     echo $id;
     echo $cont;

endwhile;

?>

</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the storage encoding to UTF-8 and collation to utf8_general_ci (you don't speak Swedish do you?)

Set the encoding of the MySQL client to UTF-8, too.

Comment: Did what you said and stil doesnn't work
settings: DB utf8_general_ci
html: <head><meta charset="utf-8">

db data (in table is) : "šđpščžćčšđčžćčšđ ćžčš čžćčđš"

in browser it outputs: "ttt�?p�?�??�??�??�? ?�?� ?�???�"

Comment: Post your code. It's impossible to get that output from your input if you keep everything in utf8.

Comment: I don't see where you set the encoding for the client. Add `$dbx->set_charset('utf8')` to set it.

Comment: It's also possible that the data in the database is incorrectly encoded. Do you see the text correctly in DB admin tools like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: $dbx->set_charset('utf8'); solved it. thank you! It works now like a charm :)